# Does Hibernate Session release the db connection if it is not used for a long time

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I know that Hibernate Session obtains a database connection only when it is required. And I know that the connection is released when `session.close()` is called. But what I am not clear is, what happens to the connection if the session was not closed? Does hibernate automatically release the database connection after some time?

Comment: Why do you care? Long running sessions are somewhat of an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it doesn't. Depending on your environment (client or server, connection pool usage, ...) the connection behavior regarding timeout might be defined in a different layer, usually the connection pool.